How to compare two big number in javascript
Why below code output result is equal? How to compare?
var num1 = 340282000000000000000000000000000000001
var num2 = 340282000000000000000000000000000000000  // 3.402823E+38
if(num1 == num2) {
    console.log('num1 equal to num2');
} else if(num1 > num2) {
    console.log('num1 bigger than num2');
} else {
    console.log('num1 lower than num2')
}


Does this answer your question? Comparing big numbers in Javascript. Consider defining them as BigInt: var num1 = 340282000000000000000000000000000000001n;

@HaoWu Change to BigInt with n suffix WORK. Thanks.

Note that exponential notation is not meant for precision, it's an imprecise number, most of the time.
Both numbers provided result in the same exponential number.
It's possible to convert a big number to big integer just adding the suffix n:


// NOTE THAT ALL NUMBERS ARE INTEGER

let num1 = 340282000000000000000000000000000000001;
let num2 = 340282000000000000000000000000000000000;
let num3 = 340282000000000000000000000000000000001n;
let num4 = 340282000000000000000000000000000000000n;
let numC = BigInt(3.40282e+38);

console.log('num1 =', String(num1));
console.log('num2 =', String(num2));
console.log('num3 =', String(num3));
console.log('num4 =', String(num4));
console.log('numC = 3.40282e+38 =', String(numC));

console.log('num1 == num2?', num1 == num2);
console.log('num3 == num4?', num3 == num4);




What does "imprecise" mean?

@Bergi It means that it is not an exact number. An exponential notation is an approximation of a number (a big one at that). This happens because all powered number results in an even number (except zero) and all numbers multiplied by even numbers results in another even number. So, an imprecise number is a number "close enough" to the original number, but not exacly the original number.

No. A number is a number, and it has a precise mathematical value. It doesn't matter whether it's stored as binary, written on paper in decimal notation, output as a hex code, or formatted using scientific notation. Now with limited precision floating point numbers (as used by the JS number type), some input formats will have their precise (intended) values rounded, but again that has nothing to do with their notation.

@Bergi So, you tell me... Why the exponential notation uses the significant digits concept? My answer is that's because it relies on imprecision to make large numbers more readable for people. You can easily see that 3.40282e+38 is the same as 3.40282 * 10 ^ 38 which is the same as 340282 * 10 ^ 33 that is equal to 340282000000000000000000000000000000000. If you want the precise number, then write the number without using the exponential notation, because writing 3.40282000000000000000000000000000000001e+38 is way worse than writing the actual number without a notation.

Being written with less significant digits does not make a number less precise - a number on its own does not have a precision. Exponential notation exists mostly for brevity, "it relies on imprecision" is false. It's scientific notation that uses significant digits (and denoting even trailing zeroes as significant) to express the precision of the measurement.

And again, the rounding that is applied during parsing of number literals (or other strings) due to the limited precision of 64bit floating point numbers has nothing to do with exponential notation. Your answer is very misleading in that regard.

Hi it seems like you hit the  maximum value that Java can handle for an integer, for such high value, you can try :
var num1 = BigInteger("340282000000000000000000000000000000001");
var num2 = BigInteger("340282000000000000000000000000000000000");
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-class-in-java/
BigInteger class is used for the mathematical operation which involves very big integer calculations that are outside the limit of all available primitive data types.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This question is not about Java.

JavaScript != Java
